# Using ng-repeat $last as a conditional in a function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

Thankyou for taking the time to view my question.

I'm debugging a web-based application which uses tabs so the user can view data. When a tab is clicked on the current tab ID is used a parameter to `loadCurrentTabData`.

The tabs are loaded using `ng-repeat`, with the `$last` tab always given a class of `active`.

The issue I'm encountering is when the last tab is closed the second-to-last tab becomes the `$1ast` tab and is given the class of active, displaying the data to the user but without passing the correct ID to the `loadCurrentTabData` function.

The `ng-repeat` is as follows:

```
<tab ng-repeat="tab in userTabs" ng-click="loadCurrentTabData($ID)" class="tab{{tab.ID}}" active="$last">
```

I can easily think of the logic for how to overcome this, but I need to be able to reference the `$last` tab in the `ng-repeat` tab list. The logic would be something like this: (ng-click on the 'close tab' button would call this function)

```
if($last){
    loadCurrentTabData($ID-1); //Load the second-to-last tab.
} else {
    loadCurrentTabData($ID+1); //Load the next tab.
}
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated, please let me know if anything is clear.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the html from where you are passing this $last variable.

Comment: @Chuck Please edit your question, comments are not the place to post your code.